# How to share Database within pages in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am creating a to do list application. At the moment I want to add a new to do list from todolistPage.xaml and after adding, I want to take the data to be able to view in the MainPage.xaml . I am able to view it from the todolistPage but not sure how to bring it to  to another page. Hope to have some help. Thanks.
Below are my codes

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace PivotApp3
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var si = mLongListSelector.SelectedItem as PivotApp3.ViewModels.ItemViewModel;

        if (mLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ To Do List"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/todolistPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        else if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ Reminder"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/reminderPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)
        mLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
        To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
        keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
        replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
        with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

        For example:

            Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

        This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

        Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
        new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
        UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
        attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
        CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
     -->

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="DAILY ROUTINE">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="activity">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="mLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="today">

        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>

    <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
        aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
        account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
        if the System Tray is hidden.

        Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
    <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
</Grid>
```

todolistPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace PivotApp3
{
public partial class todolistPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Data context for the local database
    private ToDoDataContext toDoDB;

    // Define an observable collection property that controls can bind to.
    private ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> _toDoItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _toDoItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_toDoItems != value)
            {
                _toDoItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ToDoItems");
            }
        }
    }

    //constructor
    public todolistPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Connect to the database and instantiate data context.
        toDoDB = new ToDoDataContext(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString);

        // Data context and observable collection are children of the main page.
        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast parameter as a button.
        var button = sender as Button;

        if (button != null)
        {
            // Get a handle for the to-do item bound to the button.
            ToDoItem toDoForDelete = button.DataContext as ToDoItem;

            // Remove the to-do item from the observable collection.
            ToDoItems.Remove(toDoForDelete);

            // Remove the to-do item from the local database.
            toDoDB.ToDoItems.DeleteOnSubmit(toDoForDelete);

            // Save changes to the database.
            toDoDB.SubmitChanges();

            // Put the focus back to the main page.
            this.Focus();
        }
    }


    private void newToDoTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the text box when it gets focus.
        newToDoTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void newToDoAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new to-do item based on the text box.
        ToDoItem newToDo = new ToDoItem { ItemName = newToDoTextBox.Text };

        // Add a to-do item to the observable collection.
        ToDoItems.Add(newToDo);

        // Add a to-do item to the local database.
        toDoDB.ToDoItems.InsertOnSubmit(newToDo);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call the base method.
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        // Save changes to the database.
        toDoDB.SubmitChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Define the query to gather all of the to-do items.
        var toDoItemsInDB = from ToDoItem todo in toDoDB.ToDoItems
                            select todo;

        // Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
        ToDoItems = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>(toDoItemsInDB);

        // Call the base method.
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the app that a property has changed.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}



public class ToDoDataContext : DataContext
{
    // Specify the connection string as a static, used in main page and app.xaml.
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/ToDo.sdf";

    // Pass the connection string to the base class.
    public ToDoDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    // Specify a single table for the to-do items.
    public Table<ToDoItem> ToDoItems;
}



[Table]
public class ToDoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    // Define ID: private field, public property and database column.
    private int _toDoItemId;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ToDoItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _toDoItemId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_toDoItemId != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("ToDoItemId");
                _toDoItemId = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ToDoItemId");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define item name: private field, public property and database column.
    private string _itemName;

    [Column]
    public string ItemName
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_itemName != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("ItemName");
                _itemName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemName");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define completion value: private field, public property and database column.
    private bool _isComplete;

    [Column]
    public bool IsComplete
    {
        get
        {
            return _isComplete;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isComplete != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("IsComplete");
                _isComplete = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsComplete");
            }
        }
    }
    // Version column aids update performance.
    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary _version;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the page that a data context property changed
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    // Used to notify the data context that a data context property is about to change
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

todolistPage.xaml

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="TO DO LIST" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="add" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Bind the list box to the observable collection. -->
    <ListBox x:Name="toDoItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ToDoItems}" 
                 Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,28,210" Width="440">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="440">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsComplete, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            x:Name="deleteTaskButton"
                            BorderThickness="0"                                
                            Margin="0"
                            Click="deleteTaskButton_Click">
                        <Image Source="appbar.delete.rest.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,465,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox
                x:Name="newToDoTextBox"                    
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="add new task"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"                    
                GotFocus="newToDoTextBox_GotFocus" Margin="0,-65,0,104" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button 
                Content="add"
                x:Name="newToDoAddButton"
                Click="newToDoAddButton_Click" Margin="150,43,130,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Database Created

```
        using (ToDoDataContext db = new ToDoDataContext(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                //Create the database
                db.CreateDatabase();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your database into App.xaml.cs:

```
// Data context for the local database
public ToDoDataContext toDoDB;
```

add this code to App.xaml.cs:

```
public new static App Current 
{
    get
    {
        return (App)Application.Current;
    }
}
```

Then you can access your database everywhere by using:

```
App.Current.toDoDB...
```

Comment: at the moment, i put private ToDoDataContext toDoDB; in my todolistPage.xaml.cs . Do you mean that I should move it to app.xaml.cs? and where do i place the code that you mentioned on the second line as in by the App() class?

Comment: If you want the db to be available at all pages, you should move it to App.xaml.cs. You can leave it as private, but supply access functions in this case. The code above is just for easier access to App.Current object. You can put in where you want in the App.xaml.cs.

Comment: Do you mean by this? [Column]
        public bool IsComplete
        {
            get
            {
                return _isComplete;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isComplete != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("IsComplete");
                    _isComplete = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsComplete");
                }
            }
        } //to be put in the App.xaml.cs?

Comment: and I dont understand by the App.Current.toDoDB... Do you mean, for an example to access my database in MainPage.xaml.cs i should use that code?

Comment: Keep your database object in the App.xaml.cs. Move all the logic that works with database directly to the App.xaml.cs (store/load etc.). When you need to access db, use `App.Current.toDoDB` instead of 'toDoDB`.

Comment: Do you mean I should define all my database variables table and column in the app.xaml.cs and use app.current.tododb in my todolistPage.xaml.cs to access it?

Comment: Yes, your db will be available at the all pages in this case.

Comment: Owh thanks!! Now it make sense. But should I write the app.current.tododb  inside the constructor class or above it?

Comment: Your database should be the member of App object.

Comment: What do you mean by member of app object

Comment: I'll test it first and will seek for more help if its needed thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create class to manipulate data in sql and make it avaiable from App.xaml.cs
Here is sample code
ToDoDataViewModel class:

```
public class ToDoDataViewModel  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ToDoDataContext  db;

    public ToDoDataViewModel(string connectionString)
    {
        db = new ToDoDataContext(connectionString);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> _toDoItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems
    {
        get { return this._toDoItems; }
        set
        {
            this._toDoItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ToDoItems");
        }
    }

    public void LoadCollectionsFromDatabase()
    {
        var toDos = from todo in db.ToDoItems
                      select todo;

        _toDoItems = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>(toDos);

    }

    public void InsertToDoItem(ToDoItem item)
    {
        db.ToDoItems.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        _toDoItems.Add(item);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public void DeleteToDoItem(ToDoItem item)
    {
        db.ToDoItems.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
        _toDoItems.Remove(item);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
private static ToDoDataViewModel _viewModel;
    public static ToDoDataViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel; }
    }

//other methods of App

public App()
{
    //place this code at the and of the contructor

    CreateDb();
}

private void CreateDb()
{
    using(var db=new ToDoDataContext(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString))
    {
        if(!db.DatabaseExists())
        {
            db.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }

    _viewModel=new ToDoDataViewModel(ToDoDataContext.DBConnectionString);
    _viewModel.LoadCollectionsFromDatabase();
}
```

}

And place this code in the constructors of your pages:

```
this.DataContext=App.ViewModel;
```

This way you separated your database logic from application logic
Now you can update your newToDoAddButton_Click method as following:

```
private void newToDoAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new to-do item based on the text box.
    ToDoItem newToDo = new ToDoItem { ItemName = newToDoTextBox.Text };

//Add to-do item to the local database
App.ViewModel.InsertToDoItem(newToDo);
    this.Focus(); 
}
```

And your deleteTaskButton_Click method:

```
private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;

    if (button != null)
    {
        // Get a handle for the to-do item bound to the button.
        ToDoItem toDoForDelete = button.DataContext as ToDoItem;

        // Remove the to-do item from the local database.
        App.ViewModel.DeleteToDoItem(toDoForDelete); 
        this.Focus();           
    }
}
```